# Disjoint Sets Data Structure

Tags: set

As a logical question, in what case (And under what circumstances) should disjoint sets be useful for me? For example priority queues help me in situations where I need a higher priority element added in run-time to serve me before a lower priority element that was already in the queue... But I don't seem to find a "practical" use for disjoint sets. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question. There are many applications for disjoint sets.

Say I'm writing a package maintaining tool for my favourite OS, based on building software from sources (as may be done on the free BSDs). It needs to keep track of dependencies between packages. When building and installing a big package, it would recursively fetch, build, and install any needed dependencies.

It would be nice if I was able to launch several *independent* builds at once. I.e., it would be nice if the sets of packages that I launched a build for were *disjoint*. If they weren't, I would have to work through the *intersection* of the dependencies in serial, until I got disjoint sets.

Comment: Very simple and concrete! Thanks!